# How to add a class to the image tag within anchor tag on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, class, hover, effects

I want to add a class to the image tag within the anchor tag on hover, I'm using [LightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) to display my works and using [cssgram](http://una.im/CSSgram/) filters on hover. The class should be added to `<img class="img-responsive" src="assets/865-6219.jpg">` and also keep the img-responsive class.

HTML and CSS are working fine. Only the jQuery code might not be perfect.
Here's my Code, Please Help.

```js
$("#gallery li a").hover(function(){
  $(this).find("img").addClass("inkwell");
},function() {
  $(this).find("img").removeClass(" ");
});
```

```css
ul>li{
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(100%/4 - 0px);
}

.nak-gallery > ul > li a {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 270px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nlg1>ul>li {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.nak-gallery > ul > li a > img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nak-gallery > ul > li a:hover > img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="nak-gallery nlg1">
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li data-src="assets/865-6219.jpg" data-sub-html="#title">
      <a href="">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/865-6219.jpg">
        <div class="nak-gallery-poster">
          <img class="icon">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#gallery li a").hover(function() {
  $($(this).find("img")[0]).addClass("inkwell");
}, function() {
  $($(this).find("img")[0]).removeClass("inkwell");
});
```

According to Your html structure - it has two img tags inside anchor tag. So when you tried `.find('img')` it returns array.
Above code will pull only first array element which you want to add a class

Comment: Hi @kernal, Sorry to say, but it didn't work. Please check my code pen http://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/YWoQgq

Comment: It's my bad, I corrected my code please check once again and in you pen code, your not loading JQUERY library -please add jquery plugin then try

Comment: Yay!! It works, Thanks a lot.
Only this now, its working for all the images except the last one in the gallery. Any idea what's wrong? 
Its working fine in code pen. But not in my localhost.

Comment: Show me your complete html structure.  And if that solution works for your question you can mark it as correct answer so that you can get new privileges so that you can do more stuff here

Comment: Yeah, my complete gallery html and css is in code pen 
http://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/YWoQgq
I'm sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. I marked as correct answer.

Comment: I got it @kernal. I refined my HTML code. Now its working very fine. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamalakhanan Your HTML not rendering properly.
Check your list tag.

HTML tag syntax `<li></li>`

But you wrote `<li <a href="" ..</li>`
Anchor tag not closed, check once again your HTML in script very carefully

```
<ul id="lightgallery">
  <li data-src="http://unsplash.com/photos/GYNxcQvBNzA/download">
    <a href="">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://unsplash.com/photos/GYNxcQvBNzA/download">
      <div class="nak-gallery-poster">
        <img class="icon">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-src="http://unsplash.com/photos/hx6kTWs1sHI/download">
    <a href="">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://unsplash.com/photos/hx6kTWs1sHI/download">
      <div class="nak-gallery-poster">
        <img class="icon">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-src="http://unsplash.com/photos/i2JDnMDMYv8/download" <a="" href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="http://unsplash.com/photos/i2JDnMDMYv8/download">
    <div class="nak-gallery-poster"><img class="icon"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I corrected ypur script variable check once, Place this code in your script where slide variable is you placed.

```
var slide = '<li data-src="http://unsplash.com/photos/i2JDnMDMYv8/download">'+
  '<a href="">' +
  '<img class="img-responsive" src="http://unsplash.com/photos/i2JDnMDMYv8/download">' +
  '<div class="nak-gallery-poster">' +
  '<img class="icon">' +
  '</div>' +
  '</a></li>';
```

Comment: I'm sorry, My mistake. I should have checked it before. BTW, I'm a novice in jQuery. Any way thanks. Is there a way to add you as friend in stackOverflow